# Python can't initialize the sys module when compiling from source (3.11.1) on rhel machine

Tags: python, python-3.x

My process was:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.1/Python-3.11.1.tgz
tar -xvf Python-3.11.1.tgz
cd Python-3.11.1
./configure --enable-shared --prefix=$INSTALL_DIR --enable-optimizations
make
```

I get the following error

```
./Programs/_freeze_module importlib._bootstrap ./Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py Python/frozen_modules/importlib._bootstrap.h
Fatal Python error: _PySys_InitCore: can't initialize sys module
Python runtime state: preinitialized

Current thread 0x00007f163a9d4740 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
make[1]: *** [Python/frozen_modules/importlib._bootstrap.h] Error 1
```

What's going on? What is being done wrong?